# How to forward signals to the last-clicked QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have a few QGraphicsScene subclasses "CustomScene" all deriving from a common interface that contains the virtual functions cut(), copy(), paste(), and delete(). QGraphicsScene is the superclass, which is inherited by CustomSceneInterface, which is inherited by CustomScene. Each of the CustomScenes are shown in separate QGraphicsViews in the main window. I also have QActions for cut, copy, paste, and delete.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to send the QAction signals to whichever CustomScene was clicked on last (or whichever has "focus").

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I can just send the QAction signals to slots that check which QGraphicsView has focus and then call its scene's appropriate method. I'll need to call

```
QWidget::setFocusPolicy(Qt::ClickFocus)
```

on the QGraphicsViews to get this to work properly. If someone can think of a better solution, please let me know.

EDIT:

With Qt5 and being able to use lambda expressions as slots, I can now employ a pretty spiffy approach. First, I make a function `lastClickedScene()`, which returns whichever scene was last clicked on. Then I do `connect(actionCut, &QAction::triggered, [=]{lastClickedScene->cut();})`.